# How to fix error in step-by-step debugging of javascript in Komodo IDE?

Tags: javascript, debugging, komodo, komodo-ide

I'm using the latest version of Komodo IDE (free version).
I've set break points and set it to use Remote Debugging with chrome. But it does not stop execution at those break points.

I'm getting this error that my page **is unavailable for debugging**

[image]

[Here's a 2 min video of the issue.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q8RgC_pb4zo)